# HQL query when POJO is not relevant or available

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to perform following HQL query :

```
 select count(*) , od.itemSubtype.name from OrderDetails od inner join od.itemSubtype where od.employee = 1 group by od.itemSubtype
```

My POJOs are :

```
 OrderDetails 
 -------------
 private Integer id;
 private Employee employee;
 private Order order;
 private ItemSubtype itemSubtype;
 private Integer quantity;
 private String imageStyle;
 private String imageCapture;
 private Date workStartedOn;
 private Date workFinishedOn;


 ItemSubtype 
 -----------     
 private Integer id;
 private ItemType itemType;
 private String name;
 private Set orderDetailses = new HashSet(0);
 private Set measuresBooks = new HashSet(0);
```

As the query is not able to cast existing Pojo, I am unable to retrive result. How can I perform this query? Do I need to write a new Pojo? Also How do i get Data from iteration ?

```
      Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

       // query.setParameter("employee_id", employee_id);

        Iterator i = query.iterate();
         while (i.hasNext()) {
            Object obj = i.next();
           // how to retrive values from this obj??
         }
```

Comment: The query should return `List<Object[]>` which you can easily iterate over using a `forEach` loop or otherwise using an `Iterator` with a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can obtain the results:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("""
    select 
        count(ist.id), 
        ist.name 
    from OrderDetails od 
    inner join od.itemSubtype ist 
    where od.employee = 1 
    group by ist.name
    """
);

for(Object rows : query.list()){
    Object[] row = (Object[]) rows;
    Number count = (Number) row[0];
    String itemSubTypeName = (String) row[1];
}
```